# usb keyboard and mouse not detected during win 7 installation

Tags: windows-7, usb, keyboard, bios, mouse

I've seen other threads but I am yet to find the solution for my problem.
I'm trying to install windows 7 Pro 64 on a new HP Pavilion 550 Desktop PC with preinstalled windows 10 (work related, specific software support, blahblah..). I get the installation screen and the choice of language and region, but there is no way to interact since KB/mouse are not detected. There are no PS2 ports on the MB and switching USB ports didn't help at all (I've tried every USB 2 and 3 port available. What are my options? Is there a way to do this beside virtualization? Also, BIOS settings are a joke, virtually nothing beside secure boot crap. Thank you very much

My MB specs
HP 2B47 1.04
Chipset Skylake 07
BIOS AMI A0.18

Comment: Does your BIOS have settings for USB legacy mode?

Comment: No, it does not unfortunately.